# Inherit from DataTable and copy data from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

i have the following class:

```
public class ExcelStaticDataTable : DataTable
 {
        public ExcelStaticDataTable(string tableName): base(tableName)
        {

        }

 }
```

For other hand i have a method that returns a DataTable:

```
public DataTable Foo()
{
    return new DataTable();
}
```

Lets imagine that `Foo` returns a populated datatable, what i would like is using the method `Foo`, populate my other type like:

```
ExcelStaticDataTable specialtable=new ExcelStaticDataTable("table1");
specialtable.DefaultView.Table=Foo();
```

OR

```
ExcelStaticDataTable specialtable=new ExcelStaticDataTable("table1");
specialtable=(ExcelStaticDataTable)Foo().Copy();
```

Is there any in .Net implemented for filling my derived type with a `DataTable` instance?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot assign this `DataTable` to another instance of a class that inherits `DataTable`. You need to copy all values into the other table. Therefore you can use [`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx).

```
specialtable.Merge(Foo()); // same as t1.Merge(t2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```